# Running Ionic serve I get error: Firestore (9.16.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

Full Error:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.16.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

I'm using ionic serve on the CLI to run my ionic project which connects to firebase. Initially it worked (probably worked two times) and I could see the page with the expected data however now it overwhelmingly & consistently shows the error above.

My internet connection appears to be fine - really unsure as to why I'm seeing the error and as to why it worked a couple of times

Answer (score 0):

ok - I figured out what my specific issue.

Zscaler!! When I turn off Zscaler everything works fine.